# How to achieve S3 advertised 5,500 HEAD rps?

Tags: go, amazon-s3

Link to s3 advertised request rate (5500 rps per prefix): https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/07/amazon-s3-announces-increased-request-rate-performance/

My code:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "math/rand"
    "net/http"
    "strconv"
    "time"

    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/s3"
)

func main() {
    sess := session.Must(session.NewSession(&aws.Config{
        Region: aws.String("us-east-1"),
    }))
    client := s3.New(sess)
    for i := 0; i < 1000; i++ {
        go func() {
            r := rand.Intn(35000)
            start := time.Now()
            req, _ := client.HeadObjectRequest(&s3.HeadObjectInput{
                Key:    aws.String("one-prefix/" + strconv.Itoa(r)),
                Bucket: aws.String("MY-BUCKET"),
            })
            req.Sign()
            if _, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(req.HTTPRequest); err != nil {
                log.Println(err)
            }
            log.Println(r, "cost", time.Since(start))
        }()
    }
    <-time.After(10 * time.Second)
}
```

It takes about ~5s to finish those goroutines all together on an m5.large, so roughly 200 rps, which is just a fraction of advertised 5500 rps. Wonder what I'm doing wrong and how to yield better rps with s3?

Comment: exclude the session setup time from your numbers

Comment: run on an instance type with 100Gb networking

Comment: thanks! just played with it in a c5n.large and the response time is pretty reasonable for 1,000 reqs (939 ms), 5000 reqs (1.4s)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exclude the session setup from your timing and more importantly, use an instance type that has 100Gb networking (or more...)